# What is the most efficient way of having a placeholder char* that can be sent to free()?

Tags: c, micro-optimization

I'm working on a program which we are squeezing every little bit of performance we can get and we are now into the micro-optimizations phase (while avoiding non-strictly necessary code repetitions).

Imagine a small code like this:

```
propertyContent = gets_x_prop( propStruct );
propertyContent = ( propertyContent ? propertyContent : strdup("") );

/// ....
/// ....
/// ....

free(propertyContent)
```

Decisions were made and we are sure that the next one to consider attacking is the many many calls to strdup of an empty string.
Do keep in mind that we need to have a `char*` in that variable to ease the code that comes afterwards and make it more straightforward (avoiding mistakes with `(void*)0`)

Problem lies in how to optimize that...
So far we could only reach a custom function:

```
char* a = malloc(1);
a[0] = NULL;
```

We believe that there should be some alternative to this approach. We do not yet want to replace all `free()` with a macro that does a NULL check as we believe it would be harder for it to work out for us.

Our own measurements show that, currently, the most time taken waiting is at mallocs like the ones happening inside strdup, some of them, duping empty strings.

Comment: If you have a `propertyContent` that is itself an empty string, you *would* want to free it, and you wouldn't be able to tell it apart from your static shared empty string (unless you compare the addresses before each `free`).

Comment: You should think of `NULL` as a pointer constant, not a character constant.  It might just be integer `0`, but it might be defined as `(void*)0`.  Anyway, it's not the same thing as ASCII NUL (one L), `'\0'`.  Use that or `0` for a terminating zero byte.  Especially in the context of "before calling `free`" it's confusing to call it a NULL check.  It's only from context that we can tell you mean checking the data, not the pointer.

Comment: Have you considered *not* using strings at all for some of your properties, but instead integer enum constants?  Or not always duplicating the string, only constructing a *modified* copy if/when modification is needed?  Or have you considered trying a 3rd-party malloc e.g. with per-thread free lists to reduce contention for alloc/free, if the standard one isn't already doing that and otherwise optimized for your usage pattern?

Comment: It's perfectly safe to `free(NULL)`.  Rather than assigning an empty string, assign NULL.

Comment: *"replace all free() with a macro that does a NULL check"* - why? `free(NULL)` is fully supported in standard C, and is effectively a no-op. TL;DR : NULL is a fine marker for "there's nothing here", because never will it be more true.

Comment: `I'm working on a program which we are squeezing every little bit of performance we can get and we are now into the micro-optimizations phase` so start from the strdup :)  as a "macro" optimisation

Answer (score 7):

No need for a macro, and no need for a null check. `free(NULL)` is well defined, safe, and is a no-op.

So just remove all of the code that works around this:

```
propertyContent = gets_x_prop(propStruct);

// …

free(propertyContent);
```

Done.

---

That said, this now means `propertyContent` can be `NULL`, which means that all *usage* of it still needs to check for `NULL`, which is of course far from ideal. Having it point to a dynamically allocated empty string makes its usage a lot simpler, and consequently a lot safer. You need to decide whether the tiny increase in performance is worth giving up this safety.

If you want to ensure non-`NULL` strings but you’re worried about heap fragmentation, replace the object model with something that can represent an empty string safely and efficiently. At its simplest, this means replacing `free` as follows:

```
// Header

extern const char EMPTY[];
void mystr_free(char *);
```

```
// Implementation
const char EMPTY[] = "";

void mystr_free(char *str) {
    if (str != EMPTY) free(str);
}
```

This goes in the same direction as your (unnecessary) `NULL` check macro but with all the benefits of having a never-`NULL` string.

Comment: `str != EMPTY` - I would only fear it may not work from different translation units (assuming ex. `static const char *EMPTY` is in a header and multiple files include it and use `EMPTY`). I would rather `extern const char *EMPTY` in a header with `const char *EMPTY = ""` in one of the sources.

Comment: @KamilCuk Ah, alright. Yes, that’s a valid point if the handling of the string spans more than one TU, although I’d strongly prefer this code to be constrained to a single TU (other TUs may consume this string, but mustn’t manage it). Either way, `static` is probably not a good idea here.

Comment: I personally would keep the *pointer* const as well: `extern char const* const Empty;` that would prevent users from modifying it to point to elsewhere.

Comment: @Aconcagua Definitely! I just didn’t know you could actually do that in C, too.

Comment: The proper solution is to encapsulate `EMPTY` and not expose it in other ways than a getter function returning a `const char*`. Doesn't help performance but it much better program design.

Comment: It is still having as a `char*` in the rest that makes this not as trivial as just using `NULL`. I did forget about that, I will update the question with this.
Also, this would require redefining the free along with the change which is something we wanted to avoid if it is an option....

Comment: @brunoais Nothing in my code changes the fact that you have a `char*`. And as for redefining `free`, it’s pretty common to have custom deallocation functions, and the overhead of this should be *substantially* less than that of your various `malloc`s for the empty string. Time this carefully before dismissing it.

Comment: @Aconcagua: even better:  `const char EMPTY[] = "";` would be more efficient in many cases.  No need to make code load a pointer value from memory when you can make the address itself a link-time constant.  (On x86-64 a full static address can be used in an addressing mode but can't be an immediate.  But it still only costs 1 extra RIP-relative LEA to create the address in a register, vs. `cmp rax, [rip + EMPTY]`.  And a Linux non-PIE executable could use `cmp rax, offset EMPTY` (GAS Intel syntax) because static addresses do fit in 32-bit immediates in that case.)

Comment: On a RISC you have to construct a static address in a register anyway before using it, and this would just remove the load instruction.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting point. As the pointer is const now, I'd expect a decent compiler to optimise to the same, but your solution follows my own paradigma: don't rely on optimisation, if you can achieve the same with an *equivalently simple* alternative...

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes maybe with it being a `const`-pointer to `const` the actual pointer object might not have to get loaded, but that would require link-time optimization.  `static const int foo = 123;` works well because 1. the initializer is visible to every use case 2. the initializer is a compile-time constant, not just link-time (a static-storage address).  Let's check: https://godbolt.org/z/gBXPSp yup, GCC `-fpie` checks against `.LC0` without loading from `EMPTY`.  (more detailed comments in the Godbolt link).  But the `char *EMPTY` pointer object still exists in `.rodata` for no benefit.

Comment: @PeterCordes What did I miss? The only function getting along without the `lea` instruction is the `mystr_free_invisible_EMPTY`???

Comment: @Aconcagua: That's a cheap `lea` (purely ALU with no dependencies; only the program counter), not a load as part of a memory-source `cmp`.  (Fast only if it hits in cache).  I compiled for x86-64 with `-fpie` to show the common case, even though it means avoiding the load costs an extra uop for the front-end like I described earlier.  For a load-store ISA like ARM, this is strictly better.  https://godbolt.org/z/hm5jx5. Or with `-fPIC` if you fail to give the array hidden ELF visibility then this is better, too.  Or for Linux `-fno-pie` then `.LC0` can be a 32-bit absolute immediate for `cmp`.

Comment: I see... So our best bet is really by also redefining our free function...
If that's so, how can we work with that such that a heap empty string is distinguished from a stack empty string?

Comment: @brunoais By using the constant shown in my code, and the pointer equality test also shown in my code. If you want to generalise this beyond the empty string, look up [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks. I'll take that tomorrow. Would be great if I can somehow order gcc that a certain "" is different from all other "" and so give them different addresses